# Can't type in uitextfield because of - [general] connection to daemon was invalidated

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

When I tap in `UITextfield` to edit it, the message **"connection to daemon was invalidated"** shows up and the keyboard on my iPhone doesn't show up. I am unable to edit any `UITextfield` at the moment because of such error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am getting the same error message, but my keyboard works, appears and disappears as it should. I am using the "unspecified" keyboard with "Capitalization" through "Spell Checking" set to "None" or "No", the rest to "Default". Have you tried changing your keyboard settings to isolate the cause?

Comment: Having this same issue as well, is this an iOS bug? I'm presenting a modal view controller with a UITextView in it, when I tap to edit I am seeing this daemon error.  I didn't customize anything in the textView, its just the stock settings.

Comment: Yes, it dint cause any problems. It works fine but still it shows the warning.